# Learning resource or documentation for salesforce xamarin sdk

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, c#

I am reviewing [salesforce xamarin sdk](http://components.xamarin.com/view/SalesforceSDK/) , Gone through the sample app `accounts`.

Need more learning resource about the c# classes, methods for Salesforce namespace.
So that I can implement more features.

I am specially stuck with the logout. 
How should I implement the logout functionality in the current sample app supplied with xamarin-salesforce-sdk.

EDIT

API Reference that I found
http://componentsapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3aSalesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be pushing [out a release shortly](https://components.xamarin.com/view/SalesforceSDK?version=1.4.3.1) that will add the ability to do user "logout". As for additional documentation, yes, I agree, and we're working on that. Feel free to post more specific requests here and I'll help. P.S. I'm the guy who wrote the library.

Comment: The release is now live. As noted in the release notes, you can "logout" a user by setting: `Client.CurrentUser.RequiresReauthentication = true;`

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck on your project!

Comment: Hi @Zack, Could you please guide me that only for windows 8 application is there any c# sdk available or I can use salesforcesdk for xamarin here too(as its also c#).

Comment: @RahulGautam AFAIK, there is only the WSDL client available in C# for a Windows 8 application. The Xamarin library that I wrote does not currently support other .NET platforms. However, the core of that library is not platform specific. There are some classes that would need to be implemented for the library to be useful, however. If there is sufficient interest, we would consider doing it. Feel free to suggest it on our UserVoice forum: https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/145075-xamarin-component-ideas